# determine if value exist in tuple from mysql query in python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to determine if a value exists in a tuple from a mysql query in python. Here is my code so far:

```
  query = ("select distinct(table_schema) FROM information_schema.tables where engine = 'MyISAM' AND table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema');")

  cursor.execute(query)

  for row in cursor.fetchall():

        print ('\t %s' % row[0])

        f.write('%s \n' % row[0])

    databaseName = input('Which Database would you like to convert? ')

    databaseInput = any(databaseName in row for row in query)

    if databaseInput == False:
        print('You have entered an incorrect database name!')
    else: 
         do something...
```

I am having some trouble with the syntax. The if statement does not appear to working correctly.

Any help with the proper syntax and logic to determine whether value exist in tuple of tuples would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The logic is flawed: as you overwrite `databainput` at each iteration in your for loop, you simply test if `databasename` was in the ''last'' row...

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Proper indentation is critical in Python.

Comment: @Gerrat No, no, no. "The if statement does not appear to working correctly." indicates that the current code *is not working correctly*. This is clearly **off-topic** for Code Review. Please [be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg:  Apologies.  I'll review the site before suggesting next time.

Comment: @Gerrat Thanks, we would appreciate that. There's nothing wrong with suggesting Code Review in itself, just not on this kind of question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out not necessarily an answer to my exact question but something that does exactly what I was trying to do at the time of my original post. The problem is that using mysql.connector the values are returned to the cursor in a tuple of tuples.  I instead took each individual element from the tuple of tuples and appended it to a list I created. Here is how my code looks now:

```
query = ("select distinct(table_schema) FROM information_schema.tables where engine = 'MyISAM' AND table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema');")

cursor.execute(query)

databaseList = []

for row in cursor.fetchall():

    print ('\t %s' % row[0])

    databaseList.append(row[0])

databaseName = input('Which Database would you like to convert? ')

while databaseName not in databaseList:

    print('You have entered an invalid database name!')

    databaseName = input('Which Database would you like to convert? ')

else:
     continue doing stuff....
```

Hope this helps someone who may come across this issue in the future. Thanks.